# how to play different video file formats in android

Tags: android, ffmpeg

I am developing an android application in which one of the functionality to play video files which are downloaded from server.

In Server some files are .mp4 files which are supported by android and some files .mov files.

Here i have to play .mov files also in my application which are not supported by android.So i googled about this and i found using **ffmpeg** we solve the problem.But i did not found a good tutorial how to include ffmpeg with my android application on Windows.

Please give some guide lines about this issue.

Thanks in advance

Comment: did you check this library - [vitamio](http://vov.io/vitamio/)?

Comment: If it really solved your problem. then please write one answer with the steps you performed, and also some small code snippet if you feel required and post it else wait for a better answer.